# CMake how to copy dll after find_package()

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2022

Trying out a CMAKE Project in Visual Studio 2022 for the first time and I am trying to adapt `CmakeLists.txt` [from this repository](https://github.com/isl-org/open3d-cmake-find-package) in order to use the [Open3D library](http://www.open3d.org/).

As far as I understand, the following section means that on windows and in case Open3D was build as shared library, then the .dll file should be copied to the output folder of the project.

```
if(WIN32)
    get_target_property(open3d_type Open3D::Open3D TYPE)
    if(open3d_type STREQUAL "SHARED_LIBRARY")
        message(STATUS "Copying Open3D.dll to ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/$<CONFIG>")
        add_custom_command(TARGET Draw POST_BUILD
                           COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                                   ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/Open3D.dll
                                   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/$<CONFIG>)
    endif()
endif()
```

However, on my machine the variable `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` points to `<project-root>/out/install/x64-debug` which seems to be generated from VS2022(?).

**What I have done**

So far I have added system variable to my windows environment variables called `OPEN3D_DIR`, which points to the root of the open3d binaries (=the folder containing bin, CMake, include and lib folder of the library) With that `find_package(OPEN3D REQUIRED)` seems to work, however in the script, the variable `${OPEN3D_DIR}` points to `<OPEN3D-root>/CMake`

Basically, in short my question is how finding package paths is normally handled, where does the value for `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` come from and in general, how would one set variables, which would normally be set in the CMAKE GUI?

Comment: try `$<TARGET_FILE:Open3D::Open3D>` in place of `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/Open3D.dll`

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you this seems to do the trick, the dll is now copied to the output. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$<TARGET_FILE:Open3D::Open3D>` to get the path to the DLL from the target, you can also simplify the output directory to `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:Draw>`

`copy_if_different` might be better than `copy` to make your build a bit faster.

e.g.:

```
if(WIN32)
    get_target_property(open3d_type Open3D::Open3D TYPE)
    if(open3d_type STREQUAL "SHARED_LIBRARY")
        message(STATUS "Copying Open3D.dll to $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:Draw>")
        add_custom_command(TARGET Draw POST_BUILD
                           COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                                   $<TARGET_FILE:Open3D::Open3D>
                                   $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:Draw>)
    endif()
endif()
```

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html for more useful expressions.